# Adobe Illustrator CC ~25.000 circles vs. glyphs

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to plot a massive amount of data points (25.000 and more) and edit the resulting pdf in Illustrator. I noticed a peculiar behaviour that I want to understand better:

When I plot the datapoints (with R) as glyphs (single letters from a long text) like in [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSTgO.png)], and embed the graph in Illustrator, it is slow/sluggish, but I can still work with it.

If I plot the data as points, embed them, Illustrator can simply not cope and freezes for minutes or crashes.

A glyph contains many more bezier handles than a circle (which consists of four), why is Illustrator nevertheless much faster with glyphs than circles?

Side remark: Adobe Acrobat Reader works fine with either.

[image: Graphic with many glyphs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify work for Illustrator if you split your objects to layers. Hide layers that you don't work with and Illustrator will be much faster.

Comment: This is probably true. I could also work in path-mode. But this also does not answer my question why illustrator is faster for Glyphs than Shapes

Comment: Because glyphs can contain any amount of points, but will be called only once as a whole. Data points and their relations to other data points should be recalculated every time you cange your viewport.